# Gmail Verification Code

Tags: gmail

When I signed up for Gmail, this was sent to my secondary email address:

> Congratulations on creating your brand
>   new Gmail address, myemail@gmail.com.
>   Please keep this email for your
>   records, as it contains an important
>   verification code that you may need
>   should you ever encounter problems or
>   forget your password.
>
> You can login to your account at
>   http://mail.google.com/
>
> Enjoy!
>
> The Gmail Team
>
> Verification code:
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Unfortunately, my secondary email address was hacked. I don't want the hacker to use one account to hijack another account.

So, how do I get a new verification code or how do I invalidate this validation code?

Comment: Hi phwd, Thank you for the edit. I actually made up the Verification Code and I put in a fake email address as well. But, I really appreciate the fact that you're trying to keep people safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have access to the new account so,

1. Change your [recovery address](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6566).
2. Change your SMS and Security question.
3. Change your password

After this, the account you removed, will not be able to get the recovery link
[image: Recovery section]

```
                                 *  *  *
```

I have tried different ways to get Gmail to ask for the original verification code but in all cases I have tried, they don't ask for it.

Also testing against a recovery account I removed

1. The email account did not receive the recovery link
2. For a forgotten username the email account did receive an email but the email basically said there were no Gmail accounts associated with the current one.

Reading various forums it seems it used to ask for the verification code in a [form](https://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/request.py?hl=en&contact_type=acc_reco&ara=2&ctx=acc_reco&rd=1).
But I do not see it there anymore.

Comment: Hi phwd, Thank you for the message. I'll go ahead and do that. Would someone be able to use the Verification Code and override those changes? Thank you!

Comment: No, you revoked access of that account. See image above

Comment: Cool, thanks so much for the help phwd. I'm relaxed now.